# F# lazy eval from stream reader?

Tags: f#, evaluation, lazy-evaluation, eager

I'm running into a bug in my code that makes me think that I don't really understand some of the details about F# and lazy evaluation. I know that F# evaluates eagerly and therefore am somewhat perplexed by the following function:

```
// Open a file, then read from it. Close the file. return the data.
let getStringFromFile =  
    File.OpenRead("c:\\eo\\raw.txt")
    |> fun s -> let r = new StreamReader(s)
                let data = r.ReadToEnd
                r.Close()
                s.Close()
                data
```

When I call this in FSI:

```
> let d = getStringFromFile();;

System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot read from a closed TextReader.

at System.IO.__Error.ReaderClosed()
at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
at <StartupCode$FSI_0134>.$FSI_0134.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

This makes me think that `getStringFromFile` is being evaluated lazily--so I'm totally confused. I'm not getting something about how F# evaluates functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a quick explanation of what's happening, lets start here:

```
let getStringFromFile =  
    File.OpenRead("c:\\eo\\raw.txt")
    |> fun s -> let r = new StreamReader(s)
                let data = r.ReadToEnd
                r.Close()
                s.Close()
                data
```

You can re-write the first two lines of your function as:

```
let s = File.OpenRead(@"c:\eo\raw.txt")
```

Next, you've omitted the parentheses on this method:

```
            let data = r.ReadToEnd
            r.Close()
            s.Close()
            data
```

As a result, `data` has the type `unit -> string`. When you return this value from your function, the entire result is `unit -> string`. But look what happens in between assigning your variable and returning it: you closed you streams.

End result, when a user calls the function, the streams are already closed, resulting in the error you're seeing above.

And don't forget to dispose your objects by declaring `use whatever = ...` instead of `let whatever = ...`.

With that in mind, here's a fix:

```
let getStringFromFile() =  
    use s = File.OpenRead(@"c:\eo\raw.txt")
    use r = new StreamReader(s)
    r.ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't read from your file. You bind method `ReadToEnd` of your instance of `StreamReader` to the value `data` and then call it when you call `getStringFromFile()`. The problem is that the stream is closed at this moment.

I think you have missed the parentheses and here's the correct version:

```
// Open a file, then read from it. Close the file. return the data.
let getStringFromFile =  
    File.OpenRead("c:\\eo\\raw.txt")
    |> fun s -> let r = new StreamReader(s)
                let data = r.ReadToEnd()
                r.Close()
                s.Close()
                data
```