# Writing a seq in F# into output file

Tags: f#

I have problems writing an output file in F#. It prints an incomplete data in the output. I am not sure which part of my code is wrong or if there is any better way to do it. Below is a snapshot of the last few lines in the output file.

```
NKU12,201209121039,8960,8960,8960,8960
NKU12,201209121040,8960,8960,8960,8960
NKU12,201209121041,8960,8960,8960,8960
NKU12,201209121043,8960,8960,8960,8960
NKU12,201209121045,8960,8
```

Note that in the last line, it is incomplete.
Below is my code in F#

```
let outFile = new StreamWriter("Test.csv")

let dataFrame = lines fileName
                |> Seq.map (fun y -> y.Split([|','|]))
                |> Seq.filter (fun some function) 
                |> Seq.iter (fun y -> outFile.WriteLine(sprintf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" y.[0] (y.[1]+y.[2]) y.[3] y.[4] y.[5] y.[6]))
```

Note that in the last line, it is incomplete. If I use printfn instead of writing to a file, it will display all the information fully on the console.

Thanks
Kenneth

Answer (score 14):

Try to call outData.Flush or outData.Close and then check content of the file. Some data may still be in buffer.

Comment: @KennethGoh See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3720241/974789) for how to arrange resource-consuming classes.

Comment: @KennethGoh If it solves the problem, click that hollow checkbox next to the answer...